# What can cause reset connection when running PHP script?

Tags: php, codeigniter, connection-reset

I've developed a web application with CodeIgniter that works perfectly on my local machines (one with windows and one with Linux). When I moved it to my hosting server, connection gets reset when running one particular PHP script that does a few MySQL queries and some operations on arrays. The data I'm querying  is small, just a few tables with up to 25 records. Firefox returns "The connection was reset" after maybe 2-3 seconds. I checked the servers error logs but there was nothing there. 
Unfortunately I don't have access to Apache error logs.

What can cause this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that your script is executing for longer than PHP has been configured to allow. Admittedly, 2-3 seconds seems rather short, but it could be absurdly limited by a nasty hosting provider. The default for PHP is 30 seconds if I remember.

Comment: I checked the php.ini and the max execution time 300 seconds :)

Comment: I resolved the issue by replacing all the CI sessions with native PHP sessions. Everywhere else CI sessions worked flawlessly in my code but in one controller something was not working the way it should with this particular hosting account.

Answer (score 0):

as described by @marcin_koss , same applied to me.
I had to deactivate the code-igniter Session class and use the native PHP session.

```
session_start();
$_SESSION[]
```